# exclude element from onClick callback inside draggable.js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-ui-draggable, gsap

I'm using Draggable.js and TweenMax on my website to display an image of a map that include absolute positionned clickable markers (.marker).

here is my html :

```
<div id="container_img">

    <div class="zoom_map">

    <a class="marker" href="http://www.aaa.com"></a>
    <a class="marker" href="http://www.bbb.com"></a>

    <img src=".../map.jpg">

    </div>

</div>
```

when clicking on my map (.zoom_map), I want to remove the class "zoom_activate" of the #container_img div.
everything works perfectly fine.

```
container_img.removeClass("zoom_activate");
```

what I'm trying to do is to prevent the class "zoom activate" to be removed when clicking on the .marker link.

here is my Jquery code :

```
var container_img = $("#container_img");

var map_H = $(window).height() - 60;
    map_W = map_H * 2250 / 1590;

    $("#container_img").width(map_W).height(map_H);
    $(".zoom_map").width(map_W * 2).height(map_H * 2);

Draggable.create("#container_img .zoom_map", {

    type:"x,y",
    bounds:{top:0, left:0, width:map_W, height:map_H},
    edgeResistance:1,
    minimumMovement:100,
    onClick:function() {

        TweenLite.set("#container_img .zoom_map", {clearProps:"transform"});
        container_img.removeClass("zoom_activate");

    },

});
```

is there a way to exclude my markers from the callback function ?

```
onClick:function() {

    TweenLite.set("#container_img .zoom_map", {clearProps:"transform"});
    container_img.removeClass("zoom_activate");

},
```

thanks !

Comment: if that is of any help, jquery has .not() and ':not()' selectors

Comment: Please include enough details to recreate the issue in a minimal demo. Also, we highly recommend using [GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3-migration) as it has a smaller file size, a sleeker API, and a _bunch_ of new features.